# SQLite - Select with JOINs to Many-to-Many and One-to-Many

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got a simple recipe database that I'm attempting to write a query for that will pull in a recipe, as well as all the associated ingredients and steps. The recipe itself has a many-to-many relationship with ingredients (to promote re-use of ingredient entries) and a one-to-many relationship with steps (chances are one recipe does not have an identical step to another, so no need for re-use here).

The database is setup like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Recipe (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    recipe_name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Ingredient (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ingredient TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE RecipeIngredient (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    recipe_id INTEGER,
    ingredient_id INTEGER,
    amount REAL,
    FOREIGN KEY (recipe_id) REFERENCES Recipe(_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id) REFERENCES Ingredient(_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Step (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    instruction TEXT NOT NULL,
    number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    recipe_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (recipe_id) REFERENCES Recipe(_id)
);
```

I'm able to pull all the information for a given Recipe by _id using INNER JOINS on all the tables (which creates a ton of duplicate data), but where I'm stuck is how can I group/order this to make the data useful without requiring additional parsing of the results to get a meaningful object? Would this just be better to do in 2 queries (one for the ingredients and one for the steps)?

**UPDATE**

Adding some sample data that comes back from selecting one recipe ID, doing INNER JOINs between the tables (ordered by ingredient/step number):

```
|| recipe ||    || ingredient||  ||step||   ||step number||
"Recipe One"    "Ingredient 1"   "Step 1"         "1"
"Recipe One"    "Ingredient 1"   "Step 2"         "2"
"Recipe One"    "Ingredient 1"   "Step 3"         "3"
"Recipe One"    "Ingredient 2"   "Step 1"         "1"
"Recipe One"    "Ingredient 2"   "Step 2"         "2"
"Recipe One"    "Ingredient 2"   "Step 3"         "3"
"Recipe One"    "Ingredient 3"   "Step 1"         "1"
"Recipe One"    "Ingredient 3"   "Step 2"         "2"
"Recipe One"    "Ingredient 3"   "Step 3"         "3"
```

Comment: Show us some data and what result you want. Also show us your `INNER JOIN` with `duplicated data` and we can fix that too. You can create a working sample on sqlFiddle.com. Use `Text to DDL`  to load your db schema

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza added more information, but judging by Thorsten's answer I think I'll just be better off separating this into two queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think this through, you will notice yourself that it makes no sense to put all this in one query. What result would you expect? Step 1: Heat the oven and the ingredients are sugar, flour, and milk. Step 2: Mix sugar and flour and the ingredients are sugar, flour, and milk. Step 3: Add milk and the ingredients are sugar, flour, and milk...

What you actually want is a list of ingredients (query 1) and the steps to take (query 2).

I suppose that these queries are no problem for you, you were just confused on whether and how to combine them. The answer is simple: Don't.

If you need further help, tell me.

Comment: You are right, `Steps` doesnt have any relationship with ingredients. A different case would be if you need something like use `Ingredient A and B on step 1` but you dont have that.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but I have not worked with any SQL in a few years and am definitely rusty, so I figured asking would not hurt. Thanks for the quick answer!